# Vagrant застрял на повторном соединении default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

При попытке запустить vagrant, `vagrant up` возникает ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Ivan\projects\ubu>vagrant up
    Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
    ==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is available! You currently
    ==> default: have version '20160209.0.0'. The latest is version '20160210.0.0'. Run
    ==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
    ==> default: VirtualBox VM is already running.

    C:\Users\Ivan\projects\ubu>vagrant up
    Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
    ==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is available! You currently
    ==> default: have version '20160209.0.0'. The latest is version '20160210.0.0'. Run
    ==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
    ==> default: Couldn't find Cheffile at ./Cheffile.
    ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
        default: Adapter 1: nat
    ==> default: Forwarding ports...
        default: 80 (guest) => 8181 (host) (adapter 1)
        default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
    ==> default: Booting VM...
    ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
        default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
        default: SSH username: vagrant
        default: SSH auth method: private key
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
    Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
    the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

    If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
    Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
    are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

    If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
    working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
    problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
    Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
    as well.

    If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
    the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

    C:\Users\Ivan\projects\ubu>
```

Не понимаю почему ошибка `default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...` возникает даже в простом Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8181

end
```

пробовал указывать `config.ssh.private_key_path = "C:/Users/Ivan/.ssh/id_rsa"` и

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```

Comment: система windows 10

Comment: vagrant так или иначе использует Virtualbox, зайдите в его менеджер и посмотрите, что машина выводит на экран (возможно, потрбуется вернуть `vb.gui = true`). Вполне вероятно, что там какая-то системная ошибка, которая мешает машине нормально запуститься.

Answer (score 1):

неудачу из-за VirtualBox процессов. Она возникает, скорей всего из-за того что уже запущена виртуальная машина с настройками  `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8181` 
Эта проблема была решена так :

```
# kill all virtualbox related processes
$ ps aux | grep vbox -i | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' | xargs

restart virtualbox service


# try again
$ vagrant up
```

Comment: ваш вариант под linux, а автор вроде как под виндой..

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая проблема, решилась установкой ansible
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-ansible-on-ubuntu-14-04